# rbind text files with different length of rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to rbind two txt files with dif.length of rows ,for example:

I use this code:

```
a<-matrix(1:12,4,3)
b<-matrix(21:41,7,3)

setwd("test/")
write.table(a, file="a.txt",quote=FALSE,  row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
write.table(b, file="b.txt",quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
file_list <- list.files()
g<- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_list,FUN=function(files){scan(files,what = character())}))
```

I have this warning message:

"In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"

I want g looks like this:

```
##       [,1] [,2] [,3]
##  [1,]    1    5    9
##  [2,]    2    6   10
##  [3,]    3    7   11
##  [4,]    4    8   12
##  [5,]   21   28   35
##  [6,]   22   29   36
##  [7,]   23   30   37
##  [8,]   24   31   38
##  [9,]   25   32   39
## [10,]   26   33   40
## [11,]   27   34   41
```

Is there any solution for that as i'm new i R ?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: shouldnt you explore why you are getting this error rather than wanting a brute force solution, especially since you are new to r?

Comment: I have already explore for a solution but i did not solved that .

Comment: For a newbie your first post is  a far better first post than mine back then.  I'm not sure about what you mean, but it seems that rbind(a,b) produces the above output.

Comment: `rbind.fill` from plyr package may work.

Comment: i found this link https://psychwire.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/merge-all-files-in-a-directory-using-r-into-a-single-dataframe/
but i still have the same problem  .Thanks for your comment rawr

Comment: DJJ thanks for the comment ,im looking to rbind txt files from my dir"test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you tell it otherwise, `scan()` will read the entire file as a single atomic vector.  You could pass a list to the `what` argument, but it's much easier and safer to use a function that reads structured data.  Also, you don't want to use `what = character()` because you're reading numeric values.

`read.table()` in base R, and `fread()` from package "data.table" can do this fairly easily.

```
files <- c("a.txt", "b.txt")

## read.table()
data.matrix(do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read.table)), rownames.force = FALSE)

## fread()
library(data.table)
data.matrix(rbindlist(lapply(files, fread)))
```

Both of these return the matrix

```
#       V1 V2 V3
#  [1,]  1  5  9
#  [2,]  2  6 10
#  [3,]  3  7 11
#  [4,]  4  8 12
#  [5,] 21 28 35
#  [6,] 22 29 36
#  [7,] 23 30 37
#  [8,] 24 31 38
#  [9,] 25 32 39
# [10,] 26 33 40
# [11,] 27 34 41
```

If you really wanted to use `scan()`, you could pass a list to the `what` argument to tell it the number of columns.

```
## get number of columns
nc <- max(unlist(lapply(files, count.fields)))
## read as a list, then bind together
do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) {
    do.call(cbind, scan(x, what = as.list(double(nc)), quiet = TRUE))
}))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1    5    9
#  [2,]    2    6   10 
#  [3,]    3    7   11
#  [4,]    4    8   12
#  [5,]   21   28   35
#  [6,]   22   29   36
#  [7,]   23   30   37
#  [8,]   24   31   38
#  [9,]   25   32   39
# [10,]   26   33   40
# [11,]   27   34   41
```

But this is just `count.fields()` and then  `scan()`, which is basically what `read.table()` is doing in one step. Plus this can be risky if there are missing values in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of scan, though, I'm sure it serves its purpose in some situations.

I therefore suggest the following with read.csv and write.csv:

```
a<-matrix(1:12,4,3)
b<-matrix(21:41,7,3)

setwd("test/")
write.csv(a, file="a.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
write.csv(b, file="b.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
file_list <- list.files()
g <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_list,FUN=function(files){read.csv(files)}))
```

If you take a look at `?scan`. You may find out why you got the error. My understanding is that it is reading the table in one line:

```
 > scan('a.txt',what=character())
## Read 6 items
## [1] "V1"             ",\"V2\",\"V3\"" "1,5,9"          "2,6,10"        
## [5] "3,7,11"         "4,8,12"        
 > scan('b.txt',what=character())
## Read 9 items
## [1] "V1"             ",\"V2\",\"V3\"" "21,28,35"       "22,29,36"      
## [5] "23,30,37"       "24,31,38"       "25,32,39"       "26,33,40"      
## [9] "27,34,41"
```

Comment: Thanks DJJ for your try.That gives the same warning.You are right about the scan .Its reading the table in one line.If i had one matrix i will fix that with:     a1<-scan('a.txt',what=character()) ,a2<-matrix(a1,ncol=3, byrow=T).In my case the problem starts when rbind  2 txt files .

Comment: Sorry some typo in the code. Now it should work better.